# Multipart upload to Google Bigquery

Tags: json, rest, google-bigquery

I'm trying to formulate a body for my load job (multipart) into Bigquery. Following the example on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request#multipart:

```
-foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "configuration": {
    "load": {
      "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
      "schema": {
        "fields": [
            {"name":"word","type":"STRING"},
            {"name":"word_count","type":"INTEGER"},
            {"name":"corpus","type":"STRING"},
            {"name":"corpus_date","type":"INTEGER"}
        ]
      },
      "destinationTable": {
        "projectId":"myproject",
        "datasetId":"mydataset",
        "tableId":"mytable"
      }
    }
  }
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: */*

[MY-JSON-DATA]
--foo_bar_baz--
```

But I get the message from google saying:

"message": "Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object (e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0: "

If I look at the docs at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load it seems that the sourceUris[] is required but the example doesn't include it. My data is not in the google cloud storage but in the request. Why doesn't it detect my load details?

Thanks for any help. //Leif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the message  - looks like you are missing below

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. So I have Content-Type in my header and these are all my headers:

`Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"

Content-Length: 8564

Authorization: Bearer XXX
`
Would that be correct?
Best regardsd//L

Answer (score 0):

You were right. I had an extra space in my header for Content-Type, I saw it using fiddler and it looked like this:

`Content-Type : multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"

Thanks for your support.